# Is there a way to list live objects/used memory in JavaScriptCore?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, javascriptcore

I'm working on a project where I need to use JavaScriptCore legacy API to interface with some JS code. I want to do some profiling to make sure I'm not leaking any objects. I can't use the newer Objective-C JavaScriptCore API in my production code, but I can use it for the tests/profiling if it will help.

Is there a way to profile the live objects or used memory in the JS VM?